# Testing static classes and methods in C# .NET

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'm relatively new to unit testing, and very new to C#, but I've been trying to test code that uses static classes with static methods, and it seems like I have to write huge amounts of boilerplate code in order to test, and that code would then also probably need to be tested.

For example: I'm using the System.Web.Security.Membership class, with a method `ValidateUser` on it. It seems like I need to create an interface `IMembership` containing the method `ValidateUser`, then create a class `MembershipWrapper` that implements `IMembership`, implementing the method `ValidateUser` and passing the arguments on to the actual `Membership` class. Then I need to have properties on my class that uses the `Membership` to reference the wrapper so that I can inject the dependency for a mock object during testing.

So to test 1 line of code that uses `Membership`, I've had to create an interface, and a class, and add a property and constructor code to my class. This seems wrong, so I must be getting something wrong. How should I be going about this testing? I've had a brief look at some frameworks/libraries that do dependency injection, but they still appear to require lots of boilerplate, or a very deep understanding of what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in making your system loosely coupled. I believe you don't complain on creating constructor parameters and passing abstract dependencies to your classes. But instantiating dependencies in place looks so much easier, does it?

Also, as I pointed in comments, you can reuse wrappers later. So, that is not such useless work, as it seems from first glance.

Comment: I'm all for making my code loosely coupled, and dependency injection seems like the way to do it. It just seems like if something so basic and important for every application requires this much boilerplate code, it would have been solved, but I can't find anything that looks like it actually solves the problem.

Comment: @danpalmer actually you can use something like TypeMock to mock static methods, but that will not make your code loosely coupled

Comment: Yeah, TypeMock isn't really an option as it is paid software and I'm sticking to open source stuff as much as I can on this. But thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @danpalmer there is also Moles, which I think also can mock static members. But again, if you created Membership wrapper once, then you can 1) use it in whole application 2) reuse it in later projects. E.g. I have reusable wrapper for ConfigurationManager, which I use when start new project

Comment: That is a fair point, although hopefully all my authentication (in this example) will be handled in one location. Also Moles appears to be deprecated in favour of Fakes, which I can't depend on because of it's such high price.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right way, and think you are not testing single line of code, in this case you are writing important test to ensure that your code interacts with membership provider in the right way, this is not simple unit test rather "mock-based" integration test. I think it worth creating all these mocks and have covered by tests this part of application.

And yes, it seems overkill but no other way - either you use some helpers/libraries either wrap third-party static dependencies yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I you're not happy taking the approach of constructor injection, you could look at using [Ambient Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/07/23/ambientcontext.aspx)

You basically set up a default which will call `System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser`

You then call the exposed method on the context in your code and you can now mock it for your tests

This allows you to write less setup code, but it also hides the fact that you have a dependency, which might be a problem in the future (depending on how you're reusing code)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS2012, you can always use Shims in Microsoft Fakes for static calls (or .Net library calls too).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx

Comment: The reason I'm encountering these problems is because I'm migrating away from Fakes. I can't have a dependency on an IDE that costs so much.

Comment: @danpalmer Ok, restrictions like this weren't hinted at in your question.  That said, VS2012 Express is free.

Comment: The Fakes framework is only available in Premium and Ultimate according to the feature comparison page.

Comment: @danpalmer So it is.  For the future, if you're unable to use Visual Studio when asking a C# question, note that.  Most answerers will assume that you have access to VS if you're doing .Net development, unless stated otherwise.

Comment: Ok, I'll remember that for the future. Although I will have Visual Studio for development, it's just I can't have this project relying on VS Ultimate/Premium, it ideally needs to work in Express or possibly Professional.

Comment: @danpalmer That's fair and reasonable.  Just as with doing requirements and implementation of software, you need to note your constraints on potential solutions someone may offer.  And cost is certainly a valid constraint.